# Why can .c files contain blocks?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, clang

I think block is the Objective-C feature. Recently I am adding the block to some C source file and I found it just compile OK.

I get confused, for *.c file, should the compiler(Clang) consider it as the pure C file, why it can permit block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Clang introduces blocks

> to C and, by extension, Objective-C, C++, and Objective-C++

As you can read here in the [overview](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#id2).

Of course, using blocks makes your source incompatible with C11 standard but, you know, as long as your code is for Mac OS X only...

**EDIT**: Blocks are also available in GCC, didn't know about it.

Comment: Also available in GCC.

Answer (score 2):

Blocks were added in such a manner that they are also a "C" feature in Apple's compilers.

From Apple's [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Blocks.pdf)

> Blocks are available in GCC and Clang as shipped with the OS X v10.6
>   Xcode developer tools. You can use blocks with OS X v10.6 and later,
>   and iOS 4.0 and later. The blocks runtime is open source and can be
>   found in LLVM’s compiler-rt subproject repository. Blocks have also
>   been presented to the C standards working group as N1370: Apple’s
>   Extensions to C. As Objective-C and C++ are both derived from C,
>   blocks are designed to work with all three languages (as well as
>   Objective-C++). The syntax reflects this goal.