# What does ^{ <stmts..> }() mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax, objective-c-blocks

[image]

While reading one of LLVM static analyzer documents, I stumbled upon a *strange* operator.

```
^{ int y = x; }();
```

I know I can define a nested block inside a function like { ... }, but can we even *call* it? Also, I've never seen any usage placing **^** in front of a curly bracket block. I thought this is kind of a language extension supported by GCC and googled this with keywords like *anonymous function* or *lambda* but was of no avail. Is there anyone who has any idea about this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092207/why-can-c-files-contain-blocks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Clang 9 Documentation Language Specification for Blocks](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html) it's a *Block Literal Expression*. It has the form of (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Clang_(C,_C++,_Objective-C,_Objective-C++))):

```
^return_type ( parameters ) { function_body }
```

But:

> If the return type is omitted and the argument list is ( void ), the ( void ) argument list may also be omitted.

The following:

```
^{ int y = x; }();
```

is equal to:

```
( ^void (void) { int y = x; } )();
```

is equal to:

```
void (^f)(void) = ^void (void) { int y = x; };
f();
```

It declares a block literal that does `int y = x` and immediately after declaring executes is.

Comment: Soooo this is a C++ lambda in C?

Comment: @rubenvb looks quite similar indeed

Comment: @rubenvb yes. I think only clang/llvm generally supports it. Generally, try not to use it, it isn't that popular. In C it's popular to write portable code. Gcc has extension blocks and local functions extensions, so you do lambda functions there differently.

Comment: @KamilCuk It's popular if you write iOS or macOS code.  Blocks shouldn't be used in cross-platform code though, as you say.